# Trying to understand the return value of ftell function

Tags: c, linux, gcc, file-io, seek

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
   long int count; 
   FILE *file=NULL;

   file=fopen("sample.txt","r+");
   if(file==NULL)
   {
      printf("file open fail\n");
      return;
   }
   printf("file open succesfull\n");

   if(0!=fseek(file,1,SEEK_END))
   {
      printf("seek failed\n");
      return;
   }
   printf("seek successful\n");

   count=ftell(file);

   printf("%lu", count);

   return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
file open succesfull
seek successful
3
```

My smaple.txt file has only one char  and that is q. Why it is showing 3 here ? 
Also when I am having the file empty, then ftell() is returning 1, what is that?
Working on ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Is this under Windows?  Are there newline/carriage returns in the file?

Comment: ubuntu 12.04, as mentioned in the last line

Comment: Please post the output of `od -c sample.txt`.

Comment: od -c sample.txt: 0000000   q  \n
0000002

Comment: OK so there are 2 characters and you have seeked 1 past end-of-file = 3.

Comment: two characters means q and \n? but I did not put \n. how do i make sure that it never come?

Comment: That's got more to do with "how do I edit a file", which belongs on a different stackexchange site.  However simply using `vi` will allow you to avoid adding a newline character.  Alternatively `echo 'q' > sample.txt` will work as well.

Comment: If you created that file using a text editor it most likely appended a newline implicitly. Try `printf q > sample.txt` to get a file without newline.

Comment: Note that using `echo` will also add a newline unless you use the non-standard `-n` switch.

Comment: OT: It should be `printf("%ld", count)`; as `count` is a signed integer.

Comment: We call it "off by one" error.

Answer (score 4):

Your `fseek(file, 1, SEEK_END)` places the position one character *beyond* the end of the file. That explains why you observe `count` as one for the empty file. I guess that your file, that contains just a q, also contains a carriage return consisting of actually two characters. On character behind the end is 3, what you observed.

Comment: My guess about the sample actually containing "q\n" was confirmed in the comment section of the question.

Answer (score 2):

You use [`fseek()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fseek.3.html) incorrectly to determine the file's size via `ftell()`.

From [`man fseek()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fseek.3.html) (*italics* by me):

> **int fseek(FILE *stream, long offset, int whence);**
>
> [...] The new position, measured in bytes, is
>          obtained *by adding offset bytes to the position specified by whence*.

This line:

```
if(0!=fseek(file,1,SEEK_END))
```

positions the file pointer `1` byte **after** the end of the file.

To fix this do:

```
if (0 != fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END))
```

Comment: The file has multiple characters. Please see comments on OPs question.

Comment: I know it has, exactly 2. @Corvusoft What do you want to point me to, please?

Comment: I do not understand what you want to express with your 1st comment. And if you downvoted my answer, you might like to explain why. @Corvusoft

Answer (score 0):

You have misinterpreted the ftell & fseek functions.  Less coffee more rest :p

**ftell manpage**

> long ftell(FILE *stream);
>
> The ftell() function obtains the current value of the file position
>   indicator for the stream pointed to by stream.

**fseek manpage**

> int fseek(FILE *stream, long offset, int whence);
>
> The fseek() function sets the file position indicator for the stream
>   pointed to by stream.  The new position, measured in bytes, is
>   obtained by adding offset bytes to the position spec‐
>          ified by whence.  If whence is set to SEEK_SET, SEEK_CUR, or SEEK_END, the offset is relative to the start of the file, the current
>   position indicator, or end-of-file, respectively.   A
>          successful call to the fseek() function clears the end-of-file indicator for the stream and undoes any effects of the ungetc(3)
>   function on the same stream.

**Create sample.txt**

> echo -n 'q' > sample.txt

**File Seek Example**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    FILE* file = fopen( "sample.txt", "r" );

    if( NULL == file )
    {
        perror("Failed to open file");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("File successfully opened\n");

    long position = ftell( file );

    printf( "Position before seek: %lu\n", position );

    int status = fseek( file, 1L, SEEK_SET );

    if( 0 != status )
    {
         perror("Failed to seek");
         return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("File seek successful\n");

    position = ftell( file );

    printf( "Position after seek: %lu\n", position );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**File Size Example**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    struct stat file_status = { 0 };

    int status = stat( "sample.txt", &file_status );

    if ( 0 != status )
    {
        perror("Failed to read file status");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf( "File size: %li\n", file_status.st_size );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Build**

> gcc -o example example.c

Comment: How does this answer the question?